# Sending raw data over boost::asio

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost, boost-asio

i am attempting to send raw data over boost::asio, as boost::serialization is too slow for my needs. Following various examples and boost documentation, i have a client:

SimulationClient:

```
 void SimulationClient::sendData(std::vector<WaveformDefinition>waveformPackets) {
        socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(waveformPackets),
                receiver_endpoint,
                boost::bind(&ClientEnvironmentEngine::sendComplete, this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

I attempted Tanner Sansbury's solution below, but was unable to get it to work. However, I am having success using:

```
class WaveformReceiver {
     WaveformDefinition *buffer;

     WaveformReceiver(){
         buffer = new WaveformDefinition[MAX_WAVEFORMS];
         startReceive();
     }

     void startReceive() {
         socket_.async_receive_from(boost::asio::null_buffers(), remote_endpoint_,
               boost::bind(&WaveformReceiver::handleReceive, this,
               boost::asio::placeholders::error,
               boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
     }

     void handleReceive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
        std::size_t size/*bytes_transferred*/)
     {
          if (!error)
          {
               int available = socket_.available();
               int numWaveforms = available / sizeof(WaveformDefinition_c);
               socket_.receive(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, available));

               //copy buffer into another buffer so we can re-use the original buffer for the next read
               WaveformDefinition_c* tempBuffer = new WaveformDefinition_c[numWaveforms];
               std::memcpy ( tempBuffer, buffer, available );

               //schedule a thread to handle the array of waveforms that we copied
               threadPool.schedule( boost::bind( handleWaveforms, tempBuffer, numWaveforms));
               //start listening for more waveforms
               startReceive();
          }
     }
}
```

Tanner, or others, can you tell me if what I am doing should also work, or if i am just getting lucky that it is currently working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental part of the question is about serializing and deserializing collections.

Without controlling the compiler and architectures of both the server and client, sending raw structures is typically unsafe as the byte representation may differ between systems.  While the compiler and architecture are the same in this specific case, the `#pragma pack(1)` is irrelevant as `WAVEFORM_DATA_STRUCT` is not being written as raw memory to the socket.  Instead, a multiple buffers of memory are provided for a gathering `write` operation.

```cpp
boost::array<boost::asio::mutable_buffer,2> buffer = {{
  boost::asio::buffer(&waveformPacket->numWaveforms, ...), // &numWaveforms
  boost::asio::buffer(waveformPacket->waveforms)           // &waveforms[0]
}};
```

There are various tools to help with serializing data structures, such as [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

---

The code below will demonstrate the basics for serializing a data structure for network communication.  To simplify the code and explanation, I have chosen to focus on serialization and deserialization, rather than writing and reading from the socket.  Another example located below this section will show more of a raw approach, that assumes the same compiler and architecture.

Starting with a basic `foo` type:

```cpp
struct foo
{
  char a;
  char b;
  boost::uint16_t c;
};
```

It can be determined that the data can be packed into 4 total bytes.  Below is one possible wire reprensetation:

```
0        8       16       24       32
|--------+--------+--------+--------|
|   a    |   b    |        c        |
'--------+--------+--------+--------'
```

With the wire representation determined, two functions can be used to serialize (save) a `foo` object to a buffer, and another can be used to deserialize (load) `foo` from a buffer.  As `foo.c` is larger than a byte, the functions will also need to account for [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  I opted to use the endian byte swapping functions in the Boost.Asio detail namespace for some platform neutrality.

```cpp
/// @brief Serialize foo into a network-byte-order buffer.
void serialize(const foo& foo, unsigned char* buffer)
{
  buffer[0] = foo.a;
  buffer[1] = foo.b;

  // Handle endianness.
  using ::boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::host_to_network_short;
  boost::uint16_t c = host_to_network_short(foo.c);
  std::memcpy(&buffer[2], &c, sizeof c);
}

/// @brief Deserialize foo from a network-byte-order buffer.
void deserialize(foo& foo, const unsigned char* buffer)
{
  foo.a = buffer[0];
  foo.b = buffer[1];

  // Handle endianness.
  using ::boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::network_to_host_short;
  boost::uint16_t c;
  std::memcpy(&c, &buffer[2], sizeof c);
  foo.c = network_to_host_short(c);
}
```

With the serialization and deserialization done for `foo`, the next step is to handle a collection of `foo` objects.  Before writing the code, the wire representation needs to be determine.  In this case, I have decided to prefix a sequence of `foo` elements with a 32-bit count field.

```
0        8       16       24       32
|--------+--------+--------+--------|
|       count of foo elements [n]   |
|--------+--------+--------+--------|
|         serialized foo [0]        |
|--------+--------+--------+--------|
|         serialized foo [1]        |
|--------+--------+--------+--------|
|                ...                |
|--------+--------+--------+--------|
|         serialized foo [n-1]      |
'--------+--------+--------+--------'
```

Once again, two helper functions can be introduced to serialize and deserialize collection of `foo` objects, and will also need to account for the byte order of the count field.

```cpp
/// @brief Serialize a collection of foos into a network-byte-order buffer.
template <typename Foos>
std::vector<unsigned char> serialize(const Foos& foos)
{
  boost::uint32_t count = foos.size();

  // Allocate a buffer large enough to store:
  //   - Count of foo elements.
  //   - Each serialized foo object.
  std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(
      sizeof count +            // count
      foo_packed_size * count); // serialize foo objects

  // Handle endianness for size.
  using ::boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::host_to_network_long;
  count = host_to_network_long(count);

  // Pack size into buffer.
  unsigned char* current = &buffer[0];
  std::memcpy(current, &count, sizeof count);
  current += sizeof count; // Adjust position.

  // Pack each foo into the buffer.
  BOOST_FOREACH(const foo& foo, foos)
  {
    serialize(foo, current);
    current += foo_packed_size; // Adjust position.
  }

  return buffer;
};

/// @brief Deserialize a buffer into a collection of foo objects.
std::vector<foo> deserialize(const std::vector<unsigned char>& buffer)
{
  const unsigned char* current = &buffer[0];

  // Extract the count of elements from the buffer.
  boost::uint32_t count;
  std::memcpy(&count, current, sizeof count);
  current += sizeof count;

  // Handle endianness.
  using ::boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::network_to_host_long;
  count = network_to_host_long(count);

  // With the count extracted, create the appropriate sized collection.
  std::vector<foo> foos(count);

  // Deserialize each foo from the buffer.
  BOOST_FOREACH(foo& foo, foos)
  {
    deserialize(foo, current);
    current += foo_packed_size;
  }

  return foos;
};
```

Here is the complete example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detail/socket_ops.hpp> // endian functions
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>            // boost::tie
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp> // operator== for boost::tuple

/// @brief Mockup type.
struct foo
{
  char a;
  char b;
  boost::uint16_t c;
};

/// @brief Equality check for foo objects.
bool operator==(const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs)
{
  return boost::tie(lhs.a, lhs.b, lhs.c) ==
         boost::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b, rhs.c);
}

/// @brief Calculated byte packed size for foo.
///
/// @note char + char + uint16 = 1 + 1 + 2 = 4
static const std::size_t foo_packed_size = 4;

/// @brief Serialize foo into a network-byte-order buffer.
///
/// @detail Data is packed as follows:
///
///   0        8       16       24       32
///   |--------+--------+--------+--------|
///   |   a    |   b    |        c        |
///   '--------+--------+--------+--------'
void serialize(const foo& foo, unsigned char* buffer)
{
  buffer[0] = foo.a;
  buffer[1] = foo.b;

  // Handle endianness.
  using ::boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::host_to_network_short;
  boost::uint16_t c = host_to_network_short(foo.c);
  std::memcpy(&buffer[2], &c, sizeof c);
}

/// @brief Deserialize foo from a network-byte-order buffer.
void deserialize(foo& foo, const unsigned char* buffer)
{
  foo.a = buffer[0];
  foo.b = buffer[1];

  // Handle endianness.
  using ::boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::network_to_host_short;
  boost::uint16_t c;
  std::memcpy(&c, &buffer[2], sizeof c);
  foo.c = network_to_host_short(c);
}

/// @brief Serialize a collection of foos into a network-byte-order buffer.
///
/// @detail Data is packed as follows:
///
///   0        8       16       24       32
///   |--------+--------+--------+--------|
///   |       count of foo elements [n]   |
///   |--------+--------+--------+--------|
///   |         serialized foo [0]        |
///   |--------+--------+--------+--------|
///   |         serialized foo [1]        |
///   |--------+--------+--------+--------|
///   |                ...                |
///   |--------+--------+--------+--------|
///   |         serialized foo [n-1]      |
///   '--------+--------+--------+--------'
template <typename Foos>
std::vector<unsigned char> serialize(const Foos& foos)
{
  boost::uint32_t count = foos.size();

  // Allocate a buffer large enough to store:
  //   - Count of foo elements.
  //   - Each serialized foo object.
  std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(
      sizeof count +            // count
      foo_packed_size * count); // serialize foo objects

  // Handle endianness for size.
  using ::boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::host_to_network_long;
  count = host_to_network_long(count);

  // Pack size into buffer.
  unsigned char* current = &buffer[0];
  std::memcpy(current, &count, sizeof count);
  current += sizeof count; // Adjust position.

  // Pack each foo into the buffer.
  BOOST_FOREACH(const foo& foo, foos)
  {
    serialize(foo, current);
    current += foo_packed_size; // Adjust position.
  }

  return buffer;
};

/// @brief Deserialize a buffer into a collection of foo objects.
std::vector<foo> deserialize(const std::vector<unsigned char>& buffer)
{
  const unsigned char* current = &buffer[0];

  // Extract the count of elements from the buffer.
  boost::uint32_t count;
  std::memcpy(&count, current, sizeof count);
  current += sizeof count;

  // Handle endianness.
  using ::boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::network_to_host_long;
  count = network_to_host_long(count);

  // With the count extracted, create the appropriate sized collection.
  std::vector<foo> foos(count);

  // Deserialize each foo from the buffer.
  BOOST_FOREACH(foo& foo, foos)
  {
    deserialize(foo, current);
    current += foo_packed_size;
  }

  return foos;
};

int main()
{
  // Create a collection of foo objects with pre populated data.
  std::vector<foo> foos_expected(5);
  char a = 'a',
       b = 'A';
  boost::uint16_t c = 100;

  // Populate each element. 
  BOOST_FOREACH(foo& foo, foos_expected)
  {
    foo.a = a++;
    foo.b = b++;
    foo.c = c++;
  }

  // Serialize the collection into a buffer.
  std::vector<unsigned char> buffer = serialize(foos_expected);

  // Deserialize the buffer back into a collection.
  std::vector<foo> foos_actual = deserialize(buffer);

  // Compare the two.
  std::cout << (foos_expected == foos_actual) << std::endl; // expect 1

  // Negative test.
  foos_expected[0].c = 0;
  std::cout << (foos_expected == foos_actual) << std::endl; // expect 0
}
```

Which produces the expected results of `1` and `0`.

---

If using the same compiler and architecture, then it may be possible to reinterpret a contiguous sequence of `foo` objects from a raw buffer as an array of `foo` objects, and populate `std::vector<foo>` with copy constructors.  For example:

```
// Create and populate a contiguous sequence of foo objects.
std::vector<foo> foo1;
populate(foo1);

// Get a handle to the contiguous memory block.
const char* buffer = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&foo1[0]);

// Populate a new vector via iterator constructor.  
const foo* begin = reinterpret_cast<const foo*>(buffer);
std::vector<foo> foos2(begin, begin + foos1.size());
```

In the end, `foo1` should be equal to `foo2`.  The `foo` objects in `foo2` will be copy-constructed from the reinterpreted `foo` objects residing in memory owned by `foo1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>            // boost::tie
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp> // operator== for boost::tuple

/// @brief Mockup type.
struct foo
{
  char a;
  char b;
  boost::uint16_t c;
};

/// @brief Equality check for foo objects.
bool operator==(const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs)
{
  return boost::tie(lhs.a, lhs.b, lhs.c) ==
         boost::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b, rhs.c);
}

int main()
{
  // Create a collection of foo objects with pre populated data.
  std::vector<foo> foos_expected(5);
  char a = 'a',
       b = 'A';
  boost::uint16_t c = 100;

  // Populate each element. 
  BOOST_FOREACH(foo& foo, foos_expected)
  {
    foo.a = a++;
    foo.b = b++;
    foo.c = c++;
  }

  // Treat the collection as a raw buffer.
  const char* buffer =
      reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&foos_expected[0]);

  // Populate a new vector.  
  const foo* begin = reinterpret_cast<const foo*>(buffer);
  std::vector<foo> foos_actual(begin, begin + foos_expected.size());

  // Compare the two.
  std::cout << (foos_expected == foos_actual) << std::endl; 

  // Negative test.
  foos_expected[0].c = 0;
  std::cout << (foos_expected == foos_actual) << std::endl;
}
```

As with the other approach, this produces the expected results of `1` and `0`.

Comment: This was an incredibly detailed example, thank you. However, it seems like it may be relatively slow to do all that serialization and memcpy'ing. Is there any way to send data over sockets by just taking a chunk of contiguous memory and shoving it into a socket? Esp. if we control the endianness at each end of the connection?

Comment: @jekelija: Yes, sockets only operate on raw data; the problem is deserialization. I have expanded the answer to elaborate on how to construct `std::vector<foo>` by reinterpreting a raw buffer as an array of `foo` objects.  A similar approach should be available to construct a `WAVEFORM_DATA_STRUCT` object from a buffer once `numWaveforms` is known.

Comment: Having difficulty implementing your approach, however i had some luck with another approach, that i edited my original post to include... mind taking a look and seeing if it is also correct? Essentially i de-serialize directly into a Waveform array (i realized my original struct was unnnecessary, as i can deduct the number of of waveforms from the amount of data available for reading)

Comment: @jekelija: As long as the object type is self contained, such as a POD struct, then it should be safe to reinterpreting data as a contiguous sequence of objects.  It may be worth considering using functions to abstract oneself from the implementation detail that the raw representation is being used.

Answer (score 0):

First, its not safe to use `pragma pack(1)`. Packing can differ from different compilers/arch. Also, you will get problems on protocol change. I suggest to use [google protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) instead.

Second. You are sending `std::vector` but actual data of this vector is not inside structure `WAVEFORM_DATA_STRUCT` (vector holds its data in the heap). So, you sending **vector** and its pointer to heap to another machine, where is this pointer definetly invalid. You need to serialize your vector somehow.

P.S. There is nothing to do with boost::asio yet, this issue is about correct serializing/deserializing.

Comment: We have control over the client and server, so we are able to control the compilers and architecture in a way to allow save pragma packing.

As to your second point, my understanding from the boost documentation  [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload23.html) is that buffer(vector) essentially produces the same result as:
mutable_buffers_1(
    data.size() ? &data[0] : 0,
    data.size() * sizeof(PodType));
This therefore sends the raw data in memory from the address of the first vector element to the address of the last vector element

Comment: @jekelija about packing you are seeking for troubles. About data - you sending raw data of vector, its not what you think.. Read about how vector contain its data.

Comment: @PSIAlt: The `boost::asio::buffer()` overload for `std::vector` will represent a buffer to the `std::vector`'s contents (`&v[0]`), not the `std::vector` itself (`&v`).  The Boost.Asio [reference counted buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/buffers/reference_counted.cpp) example creates a `boost::asio::const_buffer` from a `std::vector<char>`.